# When edited the entity, I made a mistake and it cached

Tags: php, caching, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, memcached

When edited the entity, I made a mistake but I corrected it immediately, but it somehow cached, now I do not have such this in project but error still exists. I don't know have to clear doctrine cache with zend2 or what to do?

[image]

I tried:

```
-sh-4.2$ vendor/bin/doctrine-module orm:clear-cache:metadata
```

but i have error in console command doesn't work

> /usr/bin/env: php: No such file or directory

Comment: back-ups are important lol I'm not familiar with Zend but is the Cache client side or server side? If its client side, hit `f12` and hard refresh the page. Also judging your error, `boolena` is a column in the **database**.

Comment: I do not know what it is of course I tried to refresh the page and the file he was looking for an updated FTP nonsense else can someone faced, btw boolena was filed type in Entity

Comment: try debug the class that returns that error?

Comment: i can't ports closed in server :( maybe some on can help with cache clearing

Comment: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.cache.theory.html

Answer (score 0):

**The cache is corrupted**.

You can just delete the content of `\data\DoctrineORMModule\Proxy` directory (backup if you're not sure of what you are doing). Or just the file(s) corresponding to your entity(ies).

Or, if you are using Doctrine with a framework that handles the cache (as Symfony), use the framework command to clear the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Need clear the memcache - ask from Roman the url. Or use cookie on dev server type me to skype.